# Trouble with Shopify - Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a video and I am trying to get into the banner on Shopify. I have this in `index.liquid` before content:

`<iframe width="100%" height="830" src="the video hosted on wordpress site" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Problem is it does not fit width on full screen desktop. It also does not scale for mobile. All user controls are available. It does autoplay. I have read a few old threads about editing HTML in Shopify to accomplish this, but they are old and I can no long edit HTML. Since it is all in liquid now? I am pretty new to all of this, especially video.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kups.jpg)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8ZXQ.jpg)

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="830" src="the link" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Can you add screenshots showing what is the behaviour you are getting and what is expected?

Comment: Added screenshots displaying both desktop full width and page in mobile. Desktop I would prefer to remove user controls and possibly fit width. Mobile the container for the video does not scale at all... It becomes one big black page with a video half way down. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is an issue with your markup and styling. This is typically solved via the common "video wrapper" method. The code below will scale the video to 100% of the width of the element that the .video-wrapper is inside of.

html

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <iframe width="480" height="830" src="the video hosted on wordpress site" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

css

```
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
.video-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yep! Nailed it. Works great now. I still have the issue of user controls though. Any ideas? I think the code differs from provider to provider but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: What seems to be the issue with the controls?

Comment: I would like to hide controls. But they are displayed regardless. Here is the code I am using now: `<video width="100%" class="landing" muted controls autoPlay loop playsinline> 
 <source src="ling.m4v" type="video/mp4"> <source src="linkg" type="video/ogg"> </video>`

Comment: I have tried controls= with no avail. But I am new to this so I could be doing it completely wrong. I have also tried looking at psuedo and editing that way.

Comment: I'm not sure that hiding video player controls provides the best user experience. I'm sure that it's far more aesthetically pleasing. If you really want to hide them, you might be able to inspect the elements inside of the the iframe and find the class or id of the container the controls are in. You could then do something like ```iframe .control-container-class { display: none; }```